# Domino Java Agent Error

Tags: lotus-domino, javaagents

When i try an java agent to run i get this error on java console. Target property of agent is None. Trigger is "On Event, "Action Menu Selected".I do ot know what i have to do to solve this problem. Any suggestion.

```
import org.openntf.domino.*;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException;

import org.openntf.domino.ext.Session.Fixes;
import org.openntf.domino.utils.Factory;

public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase 
{ 

    public void NotesMain() 
    { 
        try 
        {

            Session session = getSession(); 
            AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext(); 

            } 
        }
        catch(Exception e) 
        { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 

    }
}
```

ERROR LINE:

```
Unexpected error while executing java agent:JavaAgent
-->java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=, offset=6
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=, offset=6
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:287)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:224)
    at lotus.domino.AgentLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:638)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:287)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:224)
    at lotus.domino.AgentLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:638)
    at lotus.domino.AgentLoader.runAgent(Unknown Source)
```

I have added this .jar file in to archive that [image: inported JAR files]

Comment: The agent runs under java 1.6 but one or more of your jars are compiled for 1.7+

Comment: I have installed Domino 9.01. FP10 IF01. 
If i use import lotus.domino.*; It works great but 
If i use import org.openntf.domino.*; I get this error. I think I could not import or run with OpenNTFAPI :( How to check it out It works or not?

Comment: I think you should use teh OpenNTF Domino API 4.4 for FP10... but I hadn't test it. BTW.: If you append jar files to your agent like this, you will run into memory leaks for sure. There are bugs on domino which will lead to it. Either use DOTS or XOTS tasks for something like this or place the jars into the JVM/lib/ext folder.